Treasury Futures Roll Hedges
When you trade the US Treasury futures roll, why do you hedge with SOFR futures contracts for TU and FV and why do you hedge the stub (with SER futures weightings)?

I don't know this trade but I suspect Sofr is being used as a proxy for the Repo Rate, which plays a role in trading the bond/futures basis.

Yeah think this is right. It's not only roll related, but more generally to look in some kind of repo rate if you haven't term financed.
